# Merge get and set functions python

Tags: python

I am implementing a class with a huge amount of variables. In that class, I want to do a get function and a set function, these functions will have 4 (2 in the example) arguments.
For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
        self.var3 = 0
        self.var4 = 0

    def get(self, arg1, arg2):
        if arg1 and arg2:
            return self.var1
        elif not arg1 and arg2:
            return self.var2
        elif arg1 and not arg2:
            return self.var3
        else:
            return self.var4

    def set(self, arg1, arg2, value):
        if arg1 and arg2:
            self.var1 = value
        elif not arg1 and arg2:
            self.var2 = value
        elif arg1 and not arg2:
            self.var3 = value
        else:
            self.var4 = value
```

As you can see, my problem is that switch-case \ if-elif-else part, that I couldn't find a way to export to one function. What is the beautiful python way to do it?

Comment: Let me guess: All these variables can either be `0` or `1`? Are you trying to impement some kind of bit field?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: @L3viathan nope, they can range from 0 to 16

Comment: @TJR regardless, use getattr and setattr. This is the "pythonic" way. Python has very powerful introspection for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

As ubadub said, it seems like [you're not actually telling us what you want to achieve](http://xyproblem.info).

If my guess that you're trying to save a field of bits is correct, you can make the whole thing very simple:

```
def get(self, arg1, arg2):
    return getattr(self, "var" + str(1+2*(1-arg2)+(1-arg1)))
```

But in that case, there are [much better ways](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/).

Comment: Can we not encourage people to do string evaluation when it's not needed? That sounds like a terrifying code mess to inherit. I accept that your answer is short and to the point, and would work, until they decide to change variable names, which is something that should **NEVER** break a program from running...

Comment: Someone coming at SO without a ton of background in Python can see your answer, see that it is "very simple", and go off and start implementing stuff like that. I've inherited code bases like that before and it makes me cringe just thinking about it. If a child asks for a gun, I wouldn't say "you probably meant a water pistol, but here's a 9mm, it's pretty simple to use"

Answer (score 1):

E.g. use an array variable and calculate an index from your arguments:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 4 * [0]

    def index(self, arg1, arg2):
        return 2*int(bool(arg1)) + int(bool(arg2))  # possible results: 0, 1, 2, 3

    def get(self, arg1, arg2):
        return self.var[self.index(arg1, arg2)]

    def set(self, arg1, arg2, value):
        self.var[self.index(arg1, arg2)] = value
```

Comment: Can we not encourage people to do string evaluation when it's not needed? That sounds like a terrifying code mess to inherit. I accept that your answer is short and to the point, and would work, until they decide to change variable names, which is something that should **NEVER** break a program from running...

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
        self.var3 = 0
        self.var4 = 0

    def view(self, arg1, arg2, value = None):
        if arg1 and arg2:
            if value is not None: self.var1 = value
            return self.var1
        elif not arg1 and arg2:
            if value is not None: self.var2 = value
            return self.var2
        elif arg1 and not arg2:
            if value is not None: self.var3 = value
            return self.var3
        else:
            if value is not None: self.var4 = value
            return self.var4
```

Then you just have something like:

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.view(0,1,1)   # Changes the value, returns to nothing
x = myclass.view(0,1) # Doesn't change value, returns to "x"
```

Not sure if you're constrained by other conditions, but you can certainly simplify this process by making all your `var` parameters a value in a list or array and indexing it based on `arg1` and `arg2` values. You can create an index numpy array like:

```
self.index = numpy.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
```

then you variable array would be

```
self.var = np.array([0,0,0,0])
```

Now your method doesn't need all those if/elifs

```
def view(self, arg1, arg2, value = None)
    if value is not None: self.var[self.index[arg1,arg2]] = value
    return self.var[self.index[arg1,arg2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully grasp it; and if you're asking how to merge the get function with the set function, I don't think that makes sense (as formulated) - either you're **setting** values on an instance, or **getting** values that are already set.

```
class Something(object):

    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4

    def getValue(self, chooseOdd, chooseFirst):
        if chooseOdd:
            choices = [self.var1, self.var3]
        else:
            choices = [self.var2, self.var4]
        index = 0 if chooseFirst else 1
        return choices[index]
```

But I might rather try something like:

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
        self.values = [var1, var2, var3, var4]

   def get(self, arg1, arg2):
       """ Either require, or manually convert, arg1, arg2 into 0, 1"""
       index = arg2 << 1 | arg1
       return self.values[index]
```